# Compound regex, with multiple regex groups

Tags: regex

I am creating a **morse code decoder**, so every character which is in between double asterisks should be strong.for example. 
`** ABC ** => < strong>ABC< /strong>`.

One asterisk with single space will be `<li>` for instance `* ** *** **** *****` the result should be. `'< li>< strong> < /strong>* < strong>** < /strong>***< /li>'`

So currently I am this far.

```
`string = "** *** **** *****"`
 `preg_match_all ('/(\*{2})(.*?)(\*{2})/',$output[1],$out)`
```

result should be

```
'< li>< strong> < /strong>* < strong>** < /strong>***< /li>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Complete morse code decoder.** I hope it will help someone else as well.

```
public function format(string $text)
{
    $rules = array(
        '/^(?!(\*\s)|(#)).*/' => 'p',
        '/^\*\s(.*)/' => 'li',
        "/(^#{1,6})(.*)/" => "h"
    );
    foreach ($rules as $rule => $replacement) {
        $matched = preg_match ($rule, $text);
        if (!empty($matched)) {
            return $parsed = preg_replace_callback ($rule, function ($output) use ($replacement, $rule) {
                if ($replacement === "h") {
                    $strongHeading = preg_match ('/^(\*{2})([\w].*?)(\*{2})$/', trim ($output[2]), $strongHeaderOutPut);
                    if ($strongHeading === 0) {
                        //multiple or single nested strong
                        $strongFound = preg_match_all ('/(\*{2})(\w.*?)(\*{2})/', trim ($output[2]), $out);
                        if ($strongFound !== 0) {
                            $multipleStrongWords = preg_replace ('/(\*{2})(\w.*?)(\*{2})/', '< strong>${2}< /strong>', $output[2]);
                            return "< h1>" . trim ($multipleStrongWords) . "< /h1>";
                        } else {
                            if ($output[1] === "#") {
                                return "< h1>" . trim ($output[2]) . "< /h1>";
                            } elseif ($output[1] === "##") {
                                return "< h2>" . trim ($output[2]) . "< /h2>";
                            } elseif ($output[1] === "###") {
                                return "< h3>" . trim ($output[2]) . "< /h3>";
                            } elseif ($output[1] === "####") {
                                return "< h4>" . trim ($output[2]) . "< /h4>";
                            } elseif ($output[1] === "#####") {
                                return "< h5>" . trim ($output[2]) . "< /h5>";
                            } elseif ($output[1] === "######") {
                                return "< h6>" . trim ($output[2]) . "< /h6>";
                            }
                        }
                    } elseif ($strongHeading === 1) {
                        return "< h1>< strong>" . trim ($strongHeaderOutPut[2]) . "< /strong>< /h1>";
                    }
                } elseif ($replacement === "p") {
                    //multiple or single nested strong
                    $strongFound = preg_match_all ('/(\*{2})(\w.*?)(\*{2})/', $output[0], $out);
                    if ($strongFound !== 0) {
                        $multipleStrongWords = preg_replace ('/(\*{2})(\w.*?)(\*{2})/', '< strong>${2}< /strong>', $output[0]);
                        return "< p>" . trim ($multipleStrongWords) . "< /p>";
                    }
                    $compoundAsterisks = preg_match_all ("/(\*{2})(\*.*?)(\*{2})/", $output[0], $out);
                    if ($compoundAsterisks !== 0) {
                        $multipleStrongWords = preg_replace ('/(\*{2})(\*.*?)(\*{2})/', '< strong>${2}< /strong>', $output[0]);
                        return "< p>" . trim ($multipleStrongWords) . "< /p>";
                    }
                    return "< p>" . trim ($output[0]) . "< /p>";
                } elseif ($replacement === "li") {
                    //multiple or single nested strong
                    $strongFound = preg_match_all ('/(\*{2})(\w.*?)(\*{2})/', $output[1], $out);
                    if ($strongFound !== 0) {
                        $multipleStrongWords = preg_replace ('/(\*{2})(\w.*?)(\*{2})/', '< strong>${2}< /strong>', $output[1]);
                        return "< li>" . ( $multipleStrongWords ) . "< /li>";
                    }
                    $compoundAsterisks = preg_match_all ("/(\*{2})(.*?\s)(\*{2})/", $output[1], $out);
                    if ($compoundAsterisks !== 0) {
                        $multipleStrongWords = preg_replace ('/(\*{2})(.*?\s)(\*{2})/', '< strong>${2}< /strong>', $output[1]);
                        return "< li>" . trim ($multipleStrongWords) . "< /li>";
                    }
                    return "< li>" . trim ($output[1]) . "< /li>";
                }
            }, $text);
        }
    }
}
```

**Tests are given below.**

```
public function test_markdown_format_to_html()
{
    $this->assertEquals ($this->mardown->format ('# dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer a neque eros. Integer pellentesque leo'), '< h1>dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer a neque eros. Integer pellentesque leo< /h1>', 'Should work for level-1 header');
    $this->assertEquals($this->mardown->format ('## consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer a neque eros. Integer pellentesque leo'), '< h2>consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer a neque eros. Integer pellentesque leo< /h2>', 'Should work for level-2 header');
    $this->assertEquals ($this->mardown->format ('### sed, viverra'), '< h3>sed, viverra< /h3>', 'Should work for level-3 header');
    $this->assertEquals ($this->mardown->format ('#### Class aptent'), '< h4>Class aptent< /h4>', 'Should work for level-4 header');
    $this->assertEquals ($this->mardown->format ('##### rutrum mi eu, finibus interdum tortor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad'), '< h5>rutrum mi eu, finibus interdum tortor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad< /h5>', 'Should work for level-5 header');
    $this->assertEquals ($this->mardown->format ('###### pellentesque leo ac blandit luctus. Sed a eros eget arcu laoreet'), '< h6>pellentesque leo ac blandit luctus. Sed a eros eget arcu laoreet< /h6>', 'Should work for level-6 header');
    $this->assertEquals ($this->mardown->format ('####### Maecenas erat dolor, euismod rutrum mi eu, finibus interdum tortor.'), '< h6># Maecenas erat dolor, euismod rutrum mi eu, finibus interdum tortor.< /h6>', 'Should for strings starting with more than 6 hashtags');
    $this->assertEquals ($this->mardown->format ('* eget'), '< li>eget< /li>', 'Should work for list items');
    $this->assertEquals ($this->mardown->format ('# **ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Maecenas rutrum nisl eu**'), '< h1>< strong>ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Maecenas rutrum nisl eu< /strong>< /h1>', 'Should work for strings with emphasis');
    $this->assertEquals ($this->mardown->format ('blandit luctus. Sed a eros eget arcu laoreet suscipit. Maecenas ac urna tincidunt, fermentum'), '< p>blandit luctus. Sed a eros eget arcu laoreet suscipit. Maecenas ac urna tincidunt, fermentum< /p>', 'Should work for text without markup');
    $this->assertEquals($this->mardown->format ('**ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.**'), '< p>< strong>ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.< /strong>< /p>', 'Should work for strings with emphasis');
    $this->assertEquals ($this->mardown->format ('suscipit. Maecenas ac urna tincidunt, **fermentum** massa sed, viverra elit. Maecenas'), '< p>suscipit. Maecenas ac urna tincidunt, < strong>fermentum< /strong> massa sed, viverra elit. Maecenas< /p>', 'Should work for strings with partial emphasis');
    $this->assertEquals ($this->mardown->format ('# rutrum mi eu, **finibus interdum** tortor. Class aptent'), '< h1>rutrum mi eu, < strong>finibus interdum< /strong> tortor. Class aptent< /h1>', 'Should work for strings with partial emphasis');
    $this->assertEquals($this->mardown->format ('* elit. Maecenas **e**rat dolor,'), '< li>elit. Maecenas < strong>e< /strong>rat dolor,< /li>', 'Should work for strings with partial emphasis');
    $this->assertEquals ($this->mardown->format ('eros eget arcu **laoreet** suscipit. Maecenas ac urna tincidunt, **fermentum** massa sed, viverra'), '< p>eros eget arcu < strong>laoreet< /strong> suscipit. Maecenas ac urna tincidunt, < strong>fermentum< /strong> massa sed, viverra< /p>', 'Should work for strings where 2 parts of the string are emphasized');
    $this->assertEquals ($this->mardown->format ('# pellentesque leo ac **blandit luctus**. Sed a eros eget **arcu laoreet suscipit. Maecenas ac**'), '< h1>pellentesque leo ac < strong>blandit luctus< /strong>. Sed a eros eget < strong>arcu laoreet suscipit. Maecenas ac< /strong>< /h1>', 'Should work for strings where 2 parts of the string are emphasized');
    $this->assertEquals ($this->mardown->format ('* **himenaeos. Maecenas** rutrum **nisl eu** bibendum sodales'), '< li>< strong>himenaeos. Maecenas< /strong> rutrum < strong>nisl eu< /strong> bibendum sodales< /li>', 'Should work for strings where 2 parts of the string are emphasized');
    $this->assertEquals ($this->mardown->format ('rutrum mi e*u, finibus **inter**dum**'), '< p>rutrum mi e*u, finibus < strong>inter< /strong>dum**< /p>', 'Should work when string contains random asterisks');
    $this->assertEquals ($this->mardown->format ('****'), '< p>****< /p>', 'Compound asterisks 1');
    $this->assertEquals ($this->mardown->format ('*****'), '< p>< strong>*< /strong>< /p>', 'Compound asterisks 2');
    $this->assertEquals ($this->mardown->format ('***** **** *** ** *'), '< p>< strong>*< /strong> < strong>** < /strong>* ** *< /p>', 'Compound asterisks 4');
    $this->assertEquals ($this->mardown->format ('* ** *** **** *****'), '< li>< strong> < /strong>* < strong>** < /strong>***< /li>', 'Compound asterisks 3');

}
```

Comment: As a reminder, while it’s acceptable to provide code-only answers, it’s often more useful for the community if you can also provide an explanation of the code and help people understand _why_ it addresses the problem. That can reduce the number of follow-up questions, and  help new developers understand the underlying concepts. Would you mind updating your question with additional detail?

Answer (score 1):

Let's try this one:

```
/\*\*(.+)\*\*/g
```

[Link to RegExr](https://regexr.com/5487g) (regexp + interactive examples).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, actually i have figure it. i have posted it out.